# Docker container does not recognize Django Formtools

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, docker-compose

I have some code that uses Django Form Tools (in particular, the SessionWizardView) . From what I can see, the Formtools appears to work outside a Docker Container but fails when it is used within one. The environment where it is working is development. The Docker container where it is not wokring is Production.

**The error message one gets is (in the log of the running contaner):**

```
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'formtools'
```

**I have installed formtools on the

```
C:\Users\dgmufasa>pip install django-formtools
Requirement already satisfied: django-formtools in c:\work\software\python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: Django>=1.8 in c:\work\software\python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\django-1.11.7-py3.6.egg (from django-formtools)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\work\software\python64bitv3.6\lib\site-packages\pytz-2017.3-py3.6.egg (from Django>=1.8->django-formtools)
```

**I have added it to INSTALLED_APPS in the settings.py file**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',

     [..snip ..]

    'formtools',
]
```

**I have used it as part of a program:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
#from django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

[... snip ...]
```

In this area (development)  it all works - but - when taking the *EXACT* same code, creating a Docker file and putting it into production,
I get errors.

```
**requirements.txt for Docker build** file
Django==1.11.7
psycopg2
Pillow==4.3.0
bcrypt==3.1.4
cffi==1.11.2
django-formtools
django-phonenumber-field==1.3.0
googlemaps==2.5.1
geocoder==1.33.0
geopy==1.11.0
pandas==0.21.1
```

**during the build where requirements.txt is being used**

```
Step 6/14 : RUN set -x &&   pip install -r requirements.txt &&  apt-get update &&   apt-get install -y alien wget libaio1 &&    wget -P /tmp/ http://oss-config-file.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/docker-config-file/tools/oracle_client/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm &&   wget -P /tmp/ http://oss-config-file.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/docker-config-file/tools/oracle_client/oracle-instantclient12.2-devel-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm &&   alien -iv /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm &&    alien -iv /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.2-devel-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm &&    pip3 install cx_Oracle &&   apt-get purge -y alien perl perl5 wget && apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get clean &&     rm -rf /tmp/oracle-* && rm -rf /usr/share/docs && rm -rf /usr/share/man
 ---> Running in 06350c1369d6
[91m+ pip install -r requirements.txt
[0mCollecting Django==1.11.7 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Downloading Django-1.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.9MB)
Collecting psycopg2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Downloading psycopg2-2.7.3.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (2.7MB)
Collecting Pillow==4.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Downloading Pillow-4.3.0-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (5.8MB)
Collecting bcrypt==3.1.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 4))
  Downloading bcrypt-3.1.4-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (54kB)
Collecting cffi==1.11.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 5))
  Downloading cffi-1.11.2-cp36-cp36m-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (419kB)
Collecting django-formtools (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading django_formtools-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (132kB)
Collecting django-phonenumber-field==1.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 7))
  Downloading django-phonenumber-field-1.3.0.tar.gz
Collecting googlemaps==2.5.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 8))
  Downloading googlemaps-2.5.1.tar.gz
```

**One can see:**
Collecting django-formtools (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))
  Downloading django_formtools-2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (132kB)

So, it looks as though Docker is collecting it - but - when running the code,

This what is being used to start the container:

> docker-compose -f $FILE_EXTRACTION/docker-compose.yml up --no-deps -d
>   web_work 2>&1

This is the error that results (coming from the log of the container):

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 655, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 205, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/code/backendworkproj/mainadmin/urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mainadmin import views
  File "/code/backendworkproj/mainadmin/views.py", line 21, in <module>
    from formtools.wizard.views import SessionWizardView
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'formtools'
```

Why is this taking place?

## Update

Here is the portion speaking to the successful installation:

```
Successfully built django-phonenumber-field googlemaps olefile pycparser future
Installing collected packages: pytz, Django, psycopg2, olefile, Pillow, six, pycparser, cffi, bcrypt, django-formtools, babel, phonenumberslite, django-phonenumber-field, certifi, urllib3, idna, chardet, requests, googlemaps, click, future, decorator, ratelim, geocoder, geopy, numpy, python-dateutil, pandas
Successfully installed Django-1.11.7 Pillow-4.3.0 babel-2.5.1 bcrypt-3.1.4 certifi-2017.11.5 cffi-1.11.2 chardet-3.0.4 click-6.7 decorator-4.1.2 django-formtools-2.1 django-phonenumber-field-1.3.0 future-0.16.0 geocoder-1.33.0 geopy-1.11.0 googlemaps-2.5.1 idna-2.6 numpy-1.13.3 olefile-0.44 pandas-0.21.1 phonenumberslite-8.8.8 psycopg2-2.7.3.2 pycparser-2.18 python-dateutil-2.6.1 pytz-2017.3 ratelim-0.1.6 requests-2.18.4 six-1.11.0 urllib3-1.22
[91m+ apt-get update
```

Python on the development machine (on Windows)

```
C:\WORK\AppPython\ContractorsClubBackofficeCode>python --version
Python 3.6.3
```

Python where Docker is doing the build (on Linux)

```
python --version
Python 2.7.12
```

I suppose I can try upgrading Python on the machine where the Docker build is taking place. Do you think that will work?

## Update

**It seems like the Dockerbuild itself was using Python 3.6.2**

```
Step 7/14 : ADD . /code/
 ---> 9b9a1988e8bf
Step 8/14 : COPY *.pth /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/      <<<<<< using python 3.6???
 ---> c66a7c622993
Step 9/14 : RUN DATABASE_URL=none python3 /code/backendworkproj/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
 ---> Running in 048fe0c7144f

[... snip ....]

Copying '/code/backendworkproj/static/images/backendwork/TCC_ICON_FRONT-70.png'
Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/base.css'
Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/changelists.css'    <<<<<< using Python 3.6???
Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/rtl.css'
Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/dashboard.css'
Copying '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/css/login.css'
[... snip ...]

Step 7/14 : ADD . /code/
 ---> 9b9a1988e8bf
Step 8/14 : COPY *.pth /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/      <<<<<< using Python 3.6???
 ---> c66a7c622993
Step 9/14 : RUN DATABASE_URL=none python3 /code/backendworkproj/manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

**Below is the Dockerfile currently in use (although, I will change the python version to 3.6.3 to see what happens)**

```
FROM python:3.6.2

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
ADD requirements.txt /code/

RUN set -x &&\
        pip install -r requirements.txt &&\
        apt-get update &&\
        apt-get install -y alien wget libaio1 &&\
        wget -P /tmp/ http://oss-config-file.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/docker-config-file/tools/oracle_client/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm &&\
        wget -P /tmp/ http://oss-config-file.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/docker-config-file/tools/oracle_client/oracle-instantclient12.2-devel-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm &&\
        alien -iv /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.2-basiclite-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm &&\
        alien -iv /tmp/oracle-instantclient12.2-devel-12.2.0.1.0-1.x86_64.rpm &&\
        pip3 install cx_Oracle &&\
        apt-get purge -y alien perl perl5 wget && apt-get -y autoremove && apt-get clean && \
        rm -rf /tmp/oracle-* && rm -rf /usr/share/docs && rm -rf /usr/share/manz`   

ADD . /code/

COPY *.pth  /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/
```

Also, are there a set of instructions that will allow one to just pull the `Formtools Git repository` and include it as a `Django app` (in a project)? Again - on the development side - it works, on the production side (where Docker is involved) it does not. Thinking using it as an app could work where using `pip install` does not ...

Comment: You've shown the logs where it is downloading it, but you've missed out the bit that says whether or not it was installed successfully.

Comment: When you run `pip install` are you sure you are installing into your Python 3 virtual environment, and not the system Python 2?

Comment: @Alasdair - thanks for info, pls see update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `pip install` in your Docker file, you are installing your packages for Python 2. Use `pip3` instead.

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

I don't think you need the `COPY *.path` line. Once you have installed all your requirements with `pip3`, the `site-packages` directory should contain everything it needs.

Comment: thanks for the info. That was the reason for the formtools not being recognized. I installed python 3.6 on the laptop. When I run "pip" and "python", these are the 3.6 versions (i.e. I never had to run pip3). I did not know that there was such a difference in the Linux (or Docker) world. Thanks again!

Comment: In linux, `python` usually refers to Python 2 (see [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/)).